# Archery skill problem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, cheats

I used the console to raise my Marksmanship 11 pts..   Shows Archery skill of 58 in green but when I go to use a perk only shows archery of 47 in white.  How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 8):

This is because you used the command modav to boost your skills rather than setav.  Modav will modify your current value by adding (or subtracting) a bonus.  Setav will set the value to exactly what you want as if it is your base.

Keep in mind that if you increase your skills via setav, you are taking experience away from yourself as you do not gain the experience as if you increased those skills through usage or training.

Comment: Hmmm... this gives me an idea for skyrim prestige mode. Hit level 70, setav all skills to 0 and try to hit level 100!